# Setting focus on <button> and making the button show focus (highlighted)

Tags: javascript, html, button, focus

My code is simple:

```
<html>
<body>
    Test
    <br>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('btn2').focus();">Button 1</button>
    <br>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="alert('Hello world');">Button 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is simple - button one will set focus to button 2. However, the focus is not visible. Only when pressing the Shift key, focus will appear. Focus can also be shown using the tab key, in order to follow focus. I want focus to be visible to the user

My question is how can I set focus and make it visible to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can try make it visible to the user by adding css to the page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

```
<style>
#btn2:focus{
   background-color: blueviolet;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

is this is what you want?

```
button:focus{
  outline: 1px solid red
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for